# Creating a cURL method in a PHP class

Tags: php, oop, curl

I'm trying to create a class that uses cURL to make requests to the Twitter API. I've done some research on object oriented programming in PHP, and I can't quite figure out how this should work. The following code returns NULL:

```
 <?php

    class twitter {

      public function curlQuery($url) {
      $ch = curl_init();

      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);

      $json = curl_exec($ch);

      curl_close($ch);

      $array = json_decode($json);
      return var_dump($array);
      }
}

$object1 = new twitter;
$object1->url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=twitterapi&count=2";
$object1->curlQuery($object1->url);

 ?>
```

Also, I'm a little unsure when to use `$this->variable` vs `$variable` in a PHP class. Shouldn't all variables mentioned in an class be referenced as `$this->variable`? Why would you ever not want to reference the variable of the current object?

Comment: I tested your code its working.

Comment: You are simply wrapping a function in a class. There is nothing to be aware of here in terms of OOP.

Comment: You can always var_dump `$json` to see if you're actually getting returned data then you'll have a better idea of the culprit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, why are you storing the url in the object, then passing that variable as a parameter to a method of that same object? Seems pointless, because then you could do somethign like:

```
$object1->url = 'blahblahblah';
$object1->curlQuery(); // <---note, no parameter
```

and then in the curlQuery method:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
```

As for `$this->variable` v.s. `$variable` in PHP, `$this->variable` makes that variable a member of the object. It'll be available to all the methods in the object. `$variable` by itself will simply be a local variable within a single method. When that method returns, the local variable is destroyed and is no longer available to other methods.

In short, use `$this->variable` for things you need persisted within the object and across multiple method calls. Use `$variable` for temporary storage within a single method.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Cleaned up the class code to reference the current object instead of storing the url in the object and passing it in as a parameter in the object's method. Works perfect.  And great explanation of `$this->variable` vs `$variable`.  That really cleared things up for me.

Answer (score 2):

When the variables are defined as properties of the class, while using them in the member functions you should use the $this->variablename. But **this doesnt mean** :
**all variables mentioned in an class be referenced as $this->variable**

You may use local variables inside the member functions in the other way. which will have scope inside the perticular function defined.

like

```
class twitter 
{
   var $apikey;

   function displayKey()
   {
     $k = 1;
     $this->apikey += $k;
     echo $this->apikey;
   }

 }
```

for referencing the apikey we use $this->apikey and for the local varibles inside the function we use the other way around.